is it possible to download pgn from view.livechesscloud links
DGT broadcasts are hosted on links that start with view.livechesscloud https://view.livechesscloud.com/#0ae3ada0-034b-4144-afc7-89257d74f7da. This shows the boards and times in real time but there is no way of checking with engines or downloading pgn. Copying the moves is also not possible from that user interface. One would have to manually grab the moves.
Are there any tools which allows downloading the games as pgn or even text?

I couldn't find a tool to get pgns. If the tournament is broadcasted on lichess, chess.com or playchess.com then getting the pgn wouldn't be an issue. But not all tournaments end up there.
However I found that it keeps continuosly polling from JSON endpoints for each game which also has the moves. You can see them in your browser developer tools network tab. An example endpoint would look like https://1.pool.livechesscloud.com/get/0ae3ada0-034b-4144-afc7-89257d74f7da/round-6/game-1.json?poll
{
    "live": false,
    "serialNr": "50301",
    "firstMove": 1716507039836,
    "chess960": 518,
    "result": "WHITEWIN",
    "comment": null,
    "clock": null,
    "moves": [
        "d4 5454+5",
        "Nf6 5455+6",
        "c4 5476+8",
        "c5 5445+40",
        "d5 +8",
        "b5 5472+2",
    ]
}

Two other endpoints are also there one for tournament metadata, other for round pairings
For convenience I also created a small tool https://view-livechesscloud-pgn.vercel.app/download . Code can be found here
